# Adobe flash and Asp.net interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

We are planning to develop a website for Insurance company. I checked many insurance company websites , many used Adobe flash to calculate the quotation and used slider controls and other UI controls.

I am planning to do the same for the website am going to design.

Please help me, What is the procedure to develop in flash?

My Datalayer is consumed through WCF service.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you are at wrong place..here you have to show what you have tried or thought till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to use flash tbh... If you just want to display some data, do it with html/javascript. If you have issues because you want to display tons of data in realtime, ok, maybe flash can help you...

But anyways, it is actually just another language you would have to learn. 
You will have to buy Adobe Flash pro if you want to do it right, its a tool to create flash applications/controls etc...

http://www.adobe.com/de/products/flash.html

Getting started videos:
http://tv.adobe.com/show/learn-flash-professional-cs4/

Comment: Nice.Valuable comments.

Comment: welcome, please also rate/set answer as answered if applicable